# How to execute a piece of code for X seconds in Andengine?

Tags: android, andengine

I need to execute some code in my game for 5 seconds using the Andengine framework. So far, I've tried with the **onTimePassed** update handler:

```
 scene.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(5f, true,new ITimerCallback() {

            public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                                    // code here
                }
```

But that only executes AFTER 5 seconds have passed by. I've also tried with the **onUpdate** but, keeping apart performance issues, there's no way I can count how many seconds have passed by since the execution entered the loop. If it helps, I only need the code to execute once per second for 5 seconds. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register an `IUpdateHandler` that tracks the total amount of elapsed time by accumulating the value in `pSecondsElapsed` and then only executing your action if the accumulated time is less than 5 seconds. Also track the elapsed time in a delay counter to execute a timer action every 1 seconds.

For example

```
public interface TimerAction {
    void execute();
}
```

public class UpdateTimer implements IUpdateHandler {
        private final Scene scene;
        private final float delay;
        private final float duration;
        private final TimerAction action;

```
    private float totalElapsed;
    private float delayElapsed;


    public UpdateTimer(final Scene scene, final float delay, final float duration, final TimerAction action) {
        this.scene = scene; 
        this.delay = delay;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
        totalElapsed += pSecondsElapsed;
        delayElapsed += pSecondsElapsed;

        if (totalElapsed >= duration) {
            scene.unregisterUpdateHandler(this);
        }

        if (delayElapsed >= delay) {
            android.util.Log.i("TAG", String.format("Timer tick @ %d", System.currentTimeMillis()));
            action.execute();
            delayElapsed = 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
    }
}
```

It would then be set up something like this

```
    scene.registerUpdateHandler(new UpdateTimer(scene, 1, 5, new TimerAction() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            android.util.Log.i("TAG", "Timer action executed!!!");
        }
    }));
```